# Call HTML page with javascript content

Tags: java, android

I am stuck at an issue, I don't know if its possible or not.

I need to call a HTML page, but the page has some content being loaded via Javascript too and I need to get that also.

Is this some how possible ?

Currently I have used plain: `new URL(url).openConnection()` and it's not returning that.

Any Help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you'll need to host a `WebView` in your application. It can be hidden if you want. Call the webview `loadUrl` to load the content you want. Handle the WebViewClient `onPageFinished` so you know all of the content has loaded, and then use the javascript bridge interface (`addJavascriptInterface`) to pass the HTML back up to the application.

Comment: I did that, but somehow its not working, its not going inside the interface method. I can't see any exceptions also.

Comment: Did you add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to your interface method?